# Delete individual elements in a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a 100 X 1 (n1) cell array with each cell holding indices of a bigger data set(100 X 100, n2). I made a nested loop in order to access each individual element(index) and compare the values of another data set with these indices with a if condition. If the condition succeeds, I want to delete that element from the  original cell array into a new cell array. However when I set the element to [] in matlab, the value of the cell array does not change. The code is below:

```
for i = 1:length(n1)
    for j = 1:length(n1{i, 1})
        if n2(i,n1{i,1}(1,j)) > n3(i) && n2(i, n1{i,1}(1,j)) > n4(n1{i, 1}(1, j))
            n1{i,1}(1,j) == [];
        end                          
    end
end
```

Comment: it gives me the following error

A null assignment can have only one non-colon index.

Comment: what is the size of `n1(i,1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take that `n1(i,1)` is always a row vector so you should use,

```
n1{i,1}(j) = [];
```

If `n1(i,1)` is not a column or row then removing an element from middle would be impossible.

for example:

```
A = {[1 2 3],[5 8 9]}
A{1,2}(1,2) = []
```

gives the error: `A null assignment can have only one non-colon index`.

But `A{1,2}(2) = []` is okey.

Comment: I also changed the loop to run backwards since the size of the cell changes with every iteration, it will result in index exceeding matrix dimensions.

Thanks

Comment: @Mechanic, you are right I forgot that. I'm glad it worked for you.